# Utf 8 encoding didn't work from a file when read data

Tags: php, utf-8, php-7.1

I use https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8 to encoding. So I have 2 files :

1. File has one row with : `magn�sienne`
2. Second file has one row with `magn�sienne`

I read both files like this

```
$return[] = $this->utf8Encoding($row);

private function utf8Encoding($datas)
{
    foreach ($datas as $key => $data) {
        $datas[$key]  = Encoding::fixUTF8($data);
    }
    return $datas;
}
```

The problem is that for one document I have the result :

```
magnésienne
```

For other file I have

```
magn?sienne
```

I understand that the problem on files. But how I can force this encoding ?
Please help me

Comment: try to change encoding of the file in notepad ++. Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8

Comment: What are the bytes actually stored in the second file? (Hint: use bin2hex in PHP)

Comment: @Joni the number of bytes are different...strange

Comment: If I wrote : 
`$bytes = mb_detect_encoding($data, "auto");` 
good file return UTF-8, and the bad file return false

Comment: But what are the bytes?